# Showing OSM source acknowledgment on the map in QGIS?

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis-3, data-source

I am using OpenStreetMap as a base layer via XYZ tiles in QGIS 3.01.

I can't seem to find a way of having source acknowledgement appear on the lower right corner of the map.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Yes I agree with you that the attribution is not shown in the lower left side of the ZXY tiles of OpenStreetMap (OSM) data. However, they added the attribution information under the `Layer Properties -> QGIS Server`:

[image]

If you want to show attribution in the layout using Print Composer then you can do the following:

- Add a text box and in the text box
- Write the following:

  attribution: [%'©[OpenStreetMap contributors, CC-BY-SA](http://osm.org/copyright) contributors'%]
- Check Render as HTML, although you will lose the link when you export your map as PDF or Image, but at least it gives you the feeling that it is an HTML link.

[image]

- Please note that you need to copy the raw text of the above attribution because it is now rendered as HTML. Please look at the image above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this on your layout to grab the atribution automatically. This is particularly handy if you have multiple base maps and want to use the active one.

- In the Print Composer, place text in the location you want to
  attribute.
- In the text properties, add in the code below and replace
  the 'Map name' with the name of your map you want to attribute:

`[%array_get(map_credits('Main name'), -1)%]`