# Citing/attributing Google basemap in QGIS for research paper

Tags: google-maps, references, basemap, attribution

I have searched Google for how to cite a Google base map in QGIS for a research paper and I cannot find the correct website for their rules for attribution.

Can somebody quickly link me to their website where it tells me what I have to say or have to annotate on the map itself (e.g. "(c) Google 2020") or do I not have to do this for a journal research paper under creative commons licenses, non-commercial projects, etc.?

I am trying to use the base map "Google Map Satellite". I can't find any attribution in the map layer metadata itself either

Also for the sake of helping other people out, what are the websites and/or procedures for citing ESRI and OpenStreetMap base maps?

Comment: https://www.google.com/intl/en-us/help/legalnotices_maps/ may help for some of your question, Google doesn't own the satellite data, thereby taking no responsibility for its accuracy, currency or fitness of purpose, it act as a distribution point for imagery that it has licensed so the cited copyright depends on who owns the data that Google is allowed to show. Normally in QGIS or ArcGIS the Google image comes with the copyright note embedded in the image automatically.

Comment: You may try working around with what @ahmadhanb suggested in his answer in [Showing OSM source acknowledgment on the map in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/299026/99589), applied for Google Maps appropriately `[%'Bilder © 2020 TerraMetrics, Kartendaten © 2020 GeoBasis-DE/BKG (©2009)'%]`

Comment: Like I said, the Google Map Satellite layer does not have the attribution information in the metadata like the OpenStreetMap base map does in that other question